# I have a java mvc based website using MySQL/Jboss/Tomcat now what?

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, jboss, web

how do you put a java website on the internet?
I develloped one wich uses an EAR deployed on a Jboss and a WAR deployed on a tomcat.

Does it means that I actually have to buy 2 "hosting solution".
One for jboss, one for tomcat and then link the tomcat to my jboss IP and send my domain name to my tomcat?

that's quite expensive compared to a HTML/PHP/MySQL website.

And by the way, why have I had to put code in EJBs, why couldn't have putted it simply int the jps's beans?

Cheers

Comment: This is off-topic for SO.  Probably belongs on [webmasters.se].

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about hosting, not programming. [https://webmasters.stackexchange.com][webmasters] would be a better fit.

Answer (score 1):

It would be much simpler if you had the webapp inside the EAR, and if you deployed only one app on JBoss (which obviously include a web container).

Even if you keep your current architecture, nothing forces you to deploy both apps on 2 different machines.

Reagarding EJBs, I find it quite strange that you chose to use EJBs if you don't know what they provide. Anyway, the main advantages they give are

- declarative (and programmatic) transaction management
- distributed transactions
- resource management (thread and connection pools, pools of beans, etc.)
- dependency injection
- JMS integration message driven beans
- declarative (and programmatic) security
- and I probably forget some